# Update a counter from a list of counters without a loop?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have a list of counters:

```
from collections import Counter
counters = [
    Counter({"coach": 1, "says": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
    Counter({"i": 2, "said": 1, "hate": 1, "basketball": 1}),
    Counter({"he": 1, "said": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
]
```

I can combine them using a loop as shown below, but I'd like to avoid the loop.

```
all_ct = Counter()
for ct in counters:
    all_ct.update(ct)
```

Using `reduce` gives an error:

```
all_ct = Counter()
reduce(all_ct.update, counters) 
>>> TypeError: update() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Is there a way to combine the counters into a single counter without using a loop?

Comment: "but I'd like to avoid the loop" but why? Why would you want to avoid that? `reduce` is just a loop anyway, probably, a less efficient one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace update() with a form that reduce can use:

```
def static_update(x, y):
    x.update(y)
    return x

all_ct = Counter()
functools.reduce(static_update, counters)
```

Comment: this is really helpful! It's also faster than the loop in my tests. I wish I understood why the original form of update didn't work though :(

Comment: @Sam the immediate problem is that `all_ct.update` takes one less parameter than `static_update`. Because `all_ct.update` is a bound-method, `self` has been bound as the first argument. But also, it returns `None`

Comment: Problem #1.  `reduce(op, [a, b, c, d])` is equivalent to `op(op(op(a, b), c), d)`.   However `update` returns `None`, so this `None` gets passed to the next call to `reduce`.  I had to create a function that returns the counter.

Comment: Problem #2.  `all_ct.update` is a bound method.  `all_ct` is cooked into the method.  It doesn't fit into the pattern of reduce, which expects a static method with no built in state.

Answer (score 3):

U can use the [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

```
all_ct = sum(counters, Counter())
```

Comment: It's probably best to avoid `sum`,  from the documentation: "This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may reject non-numeric types"

Comment: Agree with juanpa, it also is hard to read and what the intent is in my opinion

Comment: @mclslee yeah, although readability is really a small problem, the larger problem is that this is relying on an implemnetation detail that, i.e. that `sum` is supposed to only work for numeric types. It just *so happens* that it doesn't throw an error, but consider: `sum(['a','b','c'], '')` there's nothing stopping Python from throwing an error with `Counter` in the future the same as it does for strings.

Comment: the sum function is extremely slow on counters :(

Comment: @Sam yes, see my answer. The most pythonic answer is just to use a loop. it will be more performant naively, and it is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 3):

Note, counters implement `__add__` to merge the counters... So you *could* use:

```
In [3]: from collections import Counter
   ...: counters = [
   ...:     Counter({"coach": 1, "says": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...:     Counter({"i": 2, "said": 1, "hate": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...:     Counter({"he": 1, "said": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...: ]

In [4]: from operator import add

In [5]: from functools import reduce

In [6]: reduce(add, counters)
Out[6]:
Counter({'coach': 1,
         'says': 1,
         'play': 2,
         'basketball': 3,
         'i': 2,
         'said': 2,
         'hate': 1,
         'he': 1})
```

Or more simply:

```
In [7]: final = Counter()

In [8]: for c in counters:
   ...:     final += c
   ...:

In [9]: final
Out[9]:
Counter({'coach': 1,
         'says': 1,
         'play': 2,
         'basketball': 3,
         'i': 2,
         'said': 2,
         'hate': 1,
         'he': 1})
```

Note, the above is more efficient, sine it only uses one dict. If you use `reduce(add, counters)` it creates an new, intermediate counter object on each iteration

Just to illustrate what I mean, in the best case, where the keys are always repeated, you have to do double the work using the `reduce`/`sum` approach:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter
   ...: counters = [
   ...:     Counter({"coach": 1, "says": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...:     Counter({"i": 2, "said": 1, "hate": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...:     Counter({"he": 1, "said": 1, "play": 1, "basketball": 1}),
   ...: ]

In [2]: counters *= 5_000

In [3]: from functools import reduce

In [4]: from operator import add

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: data = counters.copy()
   ...: result = Counter()
   ...: for c in data:
   ...:     result += c
   ...:
21.2 ms ± 542 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: data = counters.copy()
   ...: reduce(add, counters)
   ...:
   ...:
50.9 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And I believe in the worst case (where each counter has keys disjoint from each of the rest) this will degrade to quadratic performance.

Finally, note, you *can* do an in-place add using `reduce` (not `sum`) which elimiates the performance issue:

```
In [6]: import operator

In [7]: operator.iadd?
Signature: operator.iadd(a, b, /)
Docstring: Same as a += b.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method

In [8]: reduce(operator.iadd, counters, Counter())
Out[8]:
Counter({'coach': 5000,
         'says': 5000,
         'play': 10000,
         'basketball': 15000,
         'i': 10000,
         'said': 10000,
         'hate': 5000,
         'he': 5000})
```

And note, now the performance is on par with the explicit loop:

```
In [9]: %%timeit
   ...: data = counters.copy()
   ...: reduce(operator.iadd, counters, Counter())
   ...:
   ...:
22 ms ± 224 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

However, mixing functional constructs like `reduce` with functions that have side-effects is just... ugly. Better stick to imperative code for impure functions.