# Given a list of [string, number] tuples, create a dictionary where keys are the first characters of strings and the values are sums of the numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuples, where first object is a string and second one is a number. I need to create a dictionary with using first letter of the string as a key and number (or I need to add some numbers if keys will be the same) as a value.
for example:

input

```
lst = [('Alex', 5), ('Addy', 7), ('Abdul', 2), ('Bob', 6), ('Carl', 8), ('Cal', 4)]
```

output

```
dct = {'A': 14, 'B': 6, 'C': 12}
```

Comment: I suggest you start by thinking about the steps you need to take to solve this problem. Write down those steps **in words**. Once you have an idea of the steps needed, then try to translate the words into Python code.

Comment: This is a very specific request which, I believe, won't be useful to future visitors. You should've split your task into separate subtasks: iterating over a list; extracting an item from a tuple; getting the first character from a string; operating with a dict (creating, adding keys, accessing values by keys). All of them are covered in basic Python tutorials and were asked and answered multiple times on SO already.

Answer (score 5):

The most simple, straightforward and naive way is:

```
dct = {}
for k, v lst:
    if k in v:
        dct[k] += v
    else:
        dct[k] = v
```

There are ways to progressively be more clever, the first is probably to use `.get` with the default:

```
dct = {}
for k, v in lst:
    dct[k] = dct.get(k, 0) + v
```

Finally, you can use a `collections.defaultdict`, which takes a "factory" function which will be called if the key is not there, use `int` as the factor:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in lst:
    dct[k] += v
```

NOTE: it is usually safer to create a regular dict out of this, to avoid the default behavior:

```
dct = dict(dct)
```

Or even

```
dct.default_factory = None
```

Finally, one of the more flexible ways is to create your own `dict` subclass and use [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__), this is useful if need access to the key when you are making the default value, so not particularly more helpful here, but for completion's sake:

```
class AggDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

dct = AggDict()
for k, v in dct:
    dct[k] += v
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```py
dct = defaultdict(int) # default to 0

for name, val in lst:
    dct[name[0]] += val

dct = dict(dct) # get rid of default value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Counter from collections to convert the tuples to countable key/values, then use reduce from functools to add them together:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools   import reduce

lst = [('Alex', 5), ('Addy', 7), ('Abdul', 2), ('Bob', 6), ('Carl', 8), ('Cal', 4)]

dst = reduce(Counter.__add__,(Counter({k[:1]:v}) for k,v in lst))

# Counter({'A': 14, 'C': 12, 'B': 6})
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using dunder methods directly like this. Also, this is unecessarily inefficient, and becomes polynomial time as the number of keys increase, see [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64250823/5014455)